# How to sum the mutual(reciprocal) times of two users in a big table using spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd, spark-graphx

I have a big table like below in spark:

```
(a,b,1)
(a,c,2)
(b,a,3)
(b,c,4)
(c,a,5)
```

each row represents `(user1,user2,times)`
what I want to do here is to sum the reciprocal times of each users'pair. That means,after a series of transformation,the result should look like this below:

```
(a,b,4)
(a,c,7)
(b,c,4)
```

For example, `(a,b,4)`means `(a,b,1+3)`. Notably,the users'pair in the final result is sorted to remove the duplicate.

So What can I do to achieve it? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Use `least` and `greatest` to treat `(x,y),(y,x)` pair the same (if they exist) for grouping. A way to do it in Pyspark is shown below.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
df.select(f.least(df.user1,df.user2).alias('cl'),f.greatest(df.user1,df.user2).alias('cg'),df.times) \
  .groupBy('cl','cg') \
  .agg(f.sum(times)) \
  .show(truncate = False)
```